# Please provide scenarios/conditions those fail during deserialization when a class & serialized object have same serialVersionUID?

Tags: java, serialization

Please provide scenarios/conditions those fail during deserialization when a class & serialized object have same `serialVersionUID`?

I'm looking scenarios like following

1) If a data type of an instance variable is changed then deserialization will fail

Could you please provide all such scenarios. I couldn't find such scenarios list anywhere in the internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The changes that will make deserialization fail are listed in the [Java Object Serialization Specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#6678), Section 5.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

The Exceptions  thrown from readObject() give a first impression of what could happen.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject()

- ClassNotFoundException - Class of a serialized object cannot be found.
- InvalidClassException - Something is wrong with a class used by serialization.
- StreamCorruptedException - Control information in the stream is inconsistent.
- OptionalDataException - Primitive data was found in the stream instead of objects.
- IOException - Any of the usual Input/Output related exceptions.